# Cast an array shape into a string

Tags: python, string, numpy, format, type-conversion

I need to convert the output of a 2D array's `myarray.shape` into a string, because I want to isolate the rows and columns and reassign them as height and width for an image that I've read in, WITHOUT using PIL.

I tried `(str)image1.shape` but it just gave a syntax error.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`str(image1.shape)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). If you want to then parse it (say it's `(50,2)`), you could do this:

```
myshape = str(image1.shape)  # returns '(50, 2)'
part1, part2 = myshape.split(', ')
part1 = part1[1:]  # now is '50'
part2 = part2[:-1]  # now is '2'
```

**Or**, since you're really after the numbers (I think), just skip the `str()` step and directly parse the output of `image1.shape`:

```
firstnum, secondnum = image1.shape
```

and you're done.

Comment: Thanks - yes I just needed the numbers so I used the second option you said. But I get the output as this: `240L, 360L`. Is "L" part of the numbers? Or part of the format.

Comment: @user961627 You must be using Python 2. It basically means the number is a [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long) datatype instead of an [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). You can read all about them [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).